When is the one point compactification of a topological space 2nd countable...
Question: If $X$ is a non-compact locally compact Hausdorff space which is second countable. Let $X^{*} = X \cup \{ \infty \}$ be the one point compactification of $X$. Prove that $X^{*}$ is also second countable.
Proof: One point compactification is a compact Hausdorff space. Thus $X$ is a subspace of a compact Hausdorff space. Compact Hausdorff spaces are normal. Normal spaces are regular. Subspace of a regular space is regular. By Urysohn's metrization theorem, X is metrizable (Every regular space with a countable basis is metrizable).
Let $d$ be the metric on $X$. Induce a metric $d^{*}$ on $X^{*}$ by the following rule.
$d^{*}(x,y) = d(x,y)$ for $x,y \in X$
$d^{*}(x,y) = 1$ for ($x = \infty$ and $y\in X$) or ($x \in X$ and $y = \infty$)
$d^{*}(x,y) = 0$ for $x,y = \infty$
It is clear that $d^{*}$ is a metric on $X^{*}$. Compact metrizable spaces are second countable. $X^{*}$ is second countable.
Is this proof okay?
Edit: As pointed out in the comments, this is not a metric in general. In that case, how do I proceed with the proof?

In general, that's not a metric: for instance, consider $\mathbb R$ with the usual metric. Then $d(0,3) \nleq d^(0, \infty) + d^(\infty, 3) $. Furthermore, you would need to show that the induced topology equals the one of the one point compactification.
